# mongodb create index or multiple collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that will insert a few million documents every year. My collection looks like this (using mongoose):

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MySchema = new Schema({    
    schoolID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School'
    },
    kelasID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Kelas'
    },
    studentID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Students'
    },
    positiveID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Positive'
    },
    teacherID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
    },
    actionName: {
        type: String,
    },
    actionDate: {
        type: String
    },   
    actionTime: {
        type: String
    },  
    actionMonth: {
        type: Number
    }, 
    actionYear: {
        type: Number
    }, 
    points: {
        type: Number
    },
    multiply: { 
        type: Number
    },
    totalPoints: {
        type: Number
    },
    dataType: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1  //1-normal, 2-attendance, 3-notifications, 4-parent app
    },
    remarks: {
        type: String,
    },  
    remarks2: {
        type: String,
    },  
    status: {
        type: Number,   //28 Dec 2018: Currently only used when dataType=2 (attendance). 1:On-Time, 2:Late
    }, 
});
MySchema.index({ schoolID : 1}, {kelasID : 1}, {studentID : 1}, {positiveID : 1}, {actionDate : 1})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Submission', MySchema);
```

As the document grows, querying data from it are getting slower. I have been thinking of manually creating a new collection for each year starting next year (so it would be named `Submission2021`, `Submission2022` and so on), but to do this I need to modify quite a lot of code, not to mention the hassle of doing something like

```
var mySubmission;
if (year = 2021){
    mySubmission = new Submission2021();
}else if (year = 2022)
    mySubmission = new Submission2022();
}else if (year = 2023)
    mySubmission = new Submission2032();
}
mySubmission.schoolID = 123
mySubmission.kelasID = 321
mySubmission.save()
```

So will doing index based on `year` would be better for me? But my query will involve a lot of searching through either `schoolID`, `kelasID`, `studentID`, `positiveID`, `teacherID`, `actionDate`, so I don't think creating a compound index with year and the other fields inside the collection is a good idea right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only analytical column stores will offer generally good performance for query across *any* dimension.  So you will have to consider this basic tradeoff: how many indexes do you wish to create vs. insert speed.  In mongodb, compound indexes work "left to right" so you given an index created like this:

```
db.collection.createIndex({year:1, schoolID:1, studentID:1})
```

then `find({year:2020})`, `find({year:2020,schoolID:"S1"})`, and `find({year:2020,schoolID:"S1",studentID:"X1"})` will all run fast, and the last one will run really fast because it is practically unique.  But `find({schoolID:"S1"})` will not because the "leading" component `year` is not present.  You can of course create multiple indexes.  Another thing to consider is `studentID`.  Students are unique.  And efficiently narrowing the search by year is a natural thing to do.  I might recommend starting with these two indexes:

```
db.collection.createIndex({studentID:1},  {unique:true});
db.collection.createIndex({year:1, schoolID:1});  // compound
```

These will produce "customary and expected" query results rapidly.  Of course, you can add more indexes and at a few million per *year*, I don't think you have to worry about insert performance.